# finding speed using GPS

Tags: android

In my application I am retriving speed of a device using getSpeed() method of Location class. It gives speed in meters/sec. To convert this value to km/hr I am multiplying this with 3.6. But I am getting wrong speed. ex. 580 when it is moving with speed of 40km/hr. This is my code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{   
    float mps = location.getSpeed();
    float kmh = (float) (mps*3.6);
    speed = Float.toString(kmh); 
    Toast.makeText(context,"speed :"+speed,TOAST.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the GPS or Location object being passed - Obviously you're not traveling at 161 meters per second.

Comment: I checked everything. everything seems well

Answer (score 1):

i'm using following code to get current speed and it worked for me.

```
public static final int HOUR_MULTIPLIER = 3600;
public static final Double UNIT_MULTIPLIERS[] = { 0.001, 0.000621371192 };
public static final int INDEX_MILES = 1;

localspeed = loc.getSpeed() * 1.0; 
localspeed = ((localspeed * HOUR_MULTIPLIER) * UNIT_MULTIPLIERS[INDEX_MILES]);
```

you can find tutorial from [link1](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/device-speed-demo-in-android/)  and  [link2](https://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/SpeedDemo)